Change the input IDs of Geometry Node Modifier
How can I change the input numbers of a Geometry Node Modifier? These are often mixed up, like here in the picture, where the second input is actually input 9:

I need this for a script that reads the input based on these input IDs.

No, you can't. You have to get the identifier from socket name. Let's say you get GN modifier like this:
gnmod = next(m for m in obj.modifiers if m.type=='NODES')

Then get the identifier from socket name:
inputs = gnmod.node_group.inputs
identifier = inputs["Distance"].identifier

Then you can use attribute and set it:
gnmod[identifier] = 10


Also best to use _id or something like it as the variable name as well, since id is a technically a builtin function.

gnmod = next(m for m in obj.modifiers if m.type=='NODES')

Ok thanks!
Couldn't it theoretically also work if I create the geometry nodes from scratch and make sure not to move the input sockets so that they don't have a convoluted order?
I have a lot of different geometry nodes with different input names.
Is there really no way to change these input socket IDs? By hexediting the blender file or something like that.
